# List in form outputs weird error in Play 2.1.3

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I've been struggling with the following ..

I have the two case class:

```
case class Entry_form(name: String, date: Date, debit: List[Entry_account])
case class Entry_account(amount: Double, account: Long)
```

and the associated form

```
val myForm = Form(
        mapping(
            "name"                      -> nonEmptyText,
            "date"                      -> date("dd.MM.yyyy"),
            "debit"                     -> list(mapping(
                    "amount"            -> of[Double],
                    "account"       -> longNumber
                )(Entry_account.apply)(Entry_account.unapply))
        )
        (Entry_form.apply)(Entry_form.unapply)
    )
```

And I get the following error:

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : play.api.data.Mapping[models.Entry_account]
[error]  required: play.api.mvc.RequestHeader
[error]                 )(Entry_account.apply)(Entry_account.unapply))
[error]                                       ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
```

can somebody help me out? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy. Import the following!

```
import play.api.data.format.Formats._
```

**Update**

To avoid the conflict between libraries, you can create [aliases](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/119.html)

```
import play.api.data.format.Formats.{doubleFormat => someSpecificName}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, I had this one included already and it still didn't work and should have been in conflict with some other imports I have. But I have now created a new object, imported the required libraries... not the most elegant I guess but it works..